# How to disable sign up button if checkbox is not checked?

Tags: javascript, html, validation, if-statement

I tried to put sign up page using HTML, I want to do validation, if check box is not checked, I want to disable sign-up button, is it something like I called it below? what would be specific HTML5 code?

```
EnableSubmit = function(val)
{
    var sbmt = document.getElementById("Accept");

    if (val.checked == true)
    {
        sbmt.disabled = false;
    }
    else
    {
        sbmt.disabled = true;
    }
}
```

this is my code for button and check-box UI

```
<div class="form-group">
    <a href="index.html" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" id="button">Sign Up!</a>
    <label class="terms" id="terms"><input type="checkbox"> I agree with the <a href="terms-and-conditions.html">Terms and Conditions</a></label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var EnableSubmit = function(val) {
  var lnk = document.getElementById("button");
  val ? lnk.classList.remove('disabled') : lnk.classList.add('disabled');
};

var isAgreed = function() {
  return -1 === document.getElementById("button").className.split(" ").indexOf('disabled');
};
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <a href="index.html" onclick="return isAgreed();" class="disabled btn btn-primary pull-right" id="button">Sign Up!</a>
  <label class="terms" id="terms">
    <input type="checkbox" onchange='EnableSubmit(this.checked);'>I agree with the <a href="terms-and-conditions.html">Terms and Conditions</a>
  </label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This will do the thing:

```
<input onclick="EnableSubmit(this)" type="checkbox">
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML Code

```
<div class="form-group">
    <a href="index.html" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" id="sbmt_btn" onclick="my_func()">
        Sign Up!
    </a>
    <label class="terms" id="terms">
            <input type="checkbox" id="chkbox_accept">
            I agree with the 
            <a href="terms-and-conditions.html">Terms and Conditions</a>
    </label>
```

JavaScript function

```
function my_func(){
var chk_box = document.getElementById("chkbox_accept");
var submt_btn = document.getElementById("sbmt_btn");

if (chk_box.checked == true)
{
    submt_btn.disabled = false;
}
else
{
    submt_btn.disabled = true;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you have submit button in the form with an ID of "Accept". You can give it a name of the same value and use:

```
  <input type="checkbox" onclick="this.form.Accept.disabled=!this.checked">
```

However, that doesn't guarantee that the checkbox is checked when the form is submitted. Also, if the submit button is disabled by default, users without scripting may not be able to submit the form. Consider having it enabled by default and disable it using script.